# Data structure for prefix covering

Tags: data-structures, binary-trees, information-theory, coding-theory, set-cover

I have a list $[1, 2, \ldots, T]$. I want to create a collection of subsets, such that:

1. each element belongs to a small number of subsets
2. each prefix is a union of small number of subsets (these subsets can intersect, but they must exactly cover the prefix)

For a given collection of subsets, let $F$ and $G$ be the maximums of the values from the first and second properties respectively.

**Examples**:

- *binary tree*: each elements belongs to $\log T$ subsets (so, $F = \log T$) and each prefix can be represented by a union of $\log T$ subsets ($G = \log T$)
- *prefixes* themselves, i.e. $[1]$, $[1, 2]$, $[1, 2, 3]$, $\ldots$, $[1, 2, \ldots, T]$. Here, element 1 belongs to $T$ subsets, and each
  prefix is exactly 1 subset. Therefore, $F = T$ and $G = 1$.

My question is, which structure minimises $G \log F$?

In particular, compared to binary search structure, where $F = G = \log T$, I would like to have a smaller value of $G$ in the expense of larger $F$.

My intuition is that it is possible to have $G = O(\log^w \log T)$ while $F = O(\log^k T)$, for some constant $w$ and $k$, which would give $G \log F = O(\log^{w+1} \log T)$.

On the other hand, maybe there exist some lowerbounds from coding theory?

I looked at the [van Emde Boas tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_Emde_Boas_tree), but could not improve $G \log F$.

Thank you!

Comment: The obvious parameter setting to explore is $G=2$.  Then to do better than what you've got so far, you need to have $F < \sqrt{T}$.  So I think the first natural question is, is there a way to achieve both $F<\sqrt{T}$ and $G=2$?  That seems pretty challenging.